# What's best way to roundtrip an epoch timestamp?

Tags: python

I am trying to get the epoch timestamp to roundtrip properly.  I don't understand why I don't get the same epoch ts when I do this:

```
In [1]: import datetime, pytz

In [2]: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1441151100, tz=pytz.utc).strftime("%s")
Out[2]: '1441179900'
```

I thought I am dealing with all UTC here, but for some reason `strftime` above returns a different epoch timestamp.  Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get you a round trip

```
>>> (datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1441151100, tz=pytz.utc) - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=pytz.utc)).total_seconds()
1441151100.0
```

if you're using Python 3.3+ you can simplify that to:

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1441151100, tz=pytz.utc).timestamp()
```